# Angular 5 compile html with components

Tags: angular5

I'm working on a project using angular 5 and I'm trying to render components that come from database. I have a lot of components and the user can create a page and include them as he or she wants.

This is a migration intent from a project in Angular 1.6. So, this is what I have in angular 1.6

```
<div html-angular-bind="{{$ctrl.content}}"> </div>
```

And this is html-angular-bind definition for this example:

```
angular.module('App').directive('htmlAngularBind', [
  '$compile', function($compile) {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch("$ctrl.content", function(newValue, oldValue) {
        var compiled, el, html;
        html = attrs.htmlAngularBind;
        el = angular.element(html);
        compiled = $compile(el);
        elem.html(el);
        return compiled(scope);
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

So, let's supose I have components `<component1></component1>`, `<component2></component2>`...`<component1000></component1000>` in the page created by the user. All of them get replaced by the HTML defined in those components.

The question is: Is there any way to do the same in Angular 5?

Comment: Sure, it can be done somehow, but not in the most angular-way, and I feel the amount of hoops you probably have to jump through is prohibitive. I feel this is a glaring hole in Angular 2+ and no amount of arguments I have heard (and since forgotten, because they were not very convincing, apparently) telling me that it was actually an intentional omission made me accept the wisdom of it and feel any less patronized. Hope you find a solution, I will be watching (or whip up one myself if I can be ar...ed), please do share.

Comment: Just found this, but haven't checked it out yet. It's official, so there is promise.... https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader